# Manhwa where a girl is sacrificed to a demon but the demon doesn’t kill her and instead protects her from harm

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

In the manhwa it was this girl who was sacrificed by her family to be used to summon a great demon or god who would bring power, but the demon saves her and refuses to help her family unless she allows it. The demon or god then protects her and only helps he family when she tells him to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[Sacrificed](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/sacrificed)*.

> An illegitimate daughter of Emperor Berthold Amaryllis of Visio, Ludis has spent her entire life being mistreated and pushed into the shadows. Now, with the Visio Empire standing on the precipice of destruction under the threat of Demonspawn hordes, her father finds a new use for her in **becoming the sacrifice necessary to summmon an ancient god**. But as the colossal golden eyes seem ready to consume her, she finds herself in the embrace of a mysterious man...

The synopsis covers most of the question. The main character is used as a sacrifice; this was supposed to kill her, but the god instead takes a liking to her and protects her. Since her abusive family is suddenly reliant on her (and the summoned god), they're forced to treat her better.